# Taking C code into simulink using C Caller function

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

1:- Suppose I have multiple C language Source code files, each with multiple functions that are being called in other files also.

I want to make a Simulink block of each C language source code file.

Now if I make a Simulink model with all such blocks, will it work with such interlinked functions.
Will the links be created automatically or we need to make it manually?